# notebooks not opening in mathematica 10

Tags: notebooks

I`m a guest here, and thought I could just ask you guys.

I've tried filling in mathematica's support form on their website, but all I got was an e-mail telling me to use their support form! - and I'm not phoning them! - I live in Scotland!

My problem is that I have downloaded mathematica 10 upgrade, and have opened new notebooks, closed them, and when I try to open them again, a message comes up with something about the book having potentially damaging "dynamic content" - which it doesn`t! - tried it with just saving a notebook with a simple quadratic equation in it!

If I press the "enable dynamic content - nothing happens, and I have to create blank documents in mathematica 8 that will successfully open in version 10.

What can I do about this myself, if anything?

---

I've given up using it and I'm just using my laptop with mathematica 9

the exact message is:  " this notebook contains potentially harmfull dynamic content.  Do you still wish to open?"

Comment: WOMM! I tried it with a fresh v10 install and could save/open Notebooks fine. Perhaps its a problem that occurred during Mathematica 10 upgrade, did you upgrade from version 9? 

Try uninstalling both versions (8 and 10) and only installing v10 then report back if the root cause was the upgrade or multiple versions. 

Its safe to say wolfram engineers have tested this. Please edit your question and include that **exact error message** for other people who encounter this.

Comment: Why do not you ignore this message, especially, since you know that no content is dangerous?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning, not an error. You can go to Edit->Preferences->System and include your trusted notebooks in the "Edit Trusted Directories...".

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too.I couldn't find out how to open already saved notebooks,but I managed to avoid it with new ones.
Just,use "file->Save as" or (Shift+Ctrl+s) to save the notebook to the directory you want,instead of saving when you close it.The notebooks saved in this way will work properly,at least it worked for me.