# notebooks not opening in mathematica 10 (still, 15 months later)

Tags: front-end

Many of my students have Mathematica notebooks that they cannot open. I think that it's for the same reason identified in [the other post with this title](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55793/notebooks-not-opening-in-mathematica-10) from July 2014. If you open a file, DON'T SAVE IT AS ANYTHING, do stuff, click X, then AFTER prompted "Save changes to "Untitled-1"?" you click save and name it; you will not be able to open it again.

My question is, now that it's 15 months later, has anyone figured out how to open those notebooks?

Note, I've tried the same procedure above in Mathematica 9, and the files open fine, so that bug was introduced in Mathematica 10.

Comment: The `bugs` tag is "reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug". Please don't add the tag to your own post until it has been vetted. (The previous post does not have the `bugs` tag, so it doesn't belong here until the community has decided that it is necessary.)

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Win7 V10.3 and I've never faced it before. The existence of "Enable Dynamic" button when you don't have written Dynamics yourself is possible, the fact the button doesn't work seems strange.

Comment: Do you have examples of such bad notebooks that you can show?  Maybe someone can figure out what's wrong with them then.

Comment: I've replicated this problem on several computers, all running Mathematica 10.0, some on Win7 and some on Win8.  I have confirmed that it doesn't happen with Mathematica 10.3, so something must have been done to fix the issue. However, Mathematica 10.3 will not open one of these corrupted notebooks.  I'm hoping that there is a way to open them, because some of my students cannot open any of the notebooks that they've used all semester.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't know how to attach a file to this site, but if that's possible, I have one to attach.

Comment: There is no way to attach files on this site.  But you can use some other file sharing service, such as Dropbox, any service provided by your institution, http://ge.tt/, etc.  I like the latter because it requires no sign-up.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out dropbox for 20 minutes now, but unfortunately I have to get to class soon. I'll try again later. If anyone on here has Mathematica 10.0, you should be able to produce these corrupted files yourself. Just open a notebook, type 1+1 "shift+enter", then click on the red X, and after prompted "Save changes to "Untitled-1"?", click save and name the file.  You will not be able to open the file again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with Mathematica 10.0.2 on OS X.  There's also 10.0.0 which may have been affected ... If a notebook got corrupted once, it will stay corrupted for good ... future versions likely won't open it either.

Comment: I created a Mathematica Notebook which only had one cell, a title, Joe. I saved it using the process noted above that corrupts the file, then opened it with Notepad.  It was a 739 line text file, and the word Joe was not in it, so presumably all of the information in these corrupted files is gone for good.